# Indexing a 2D numpy array with another 2D nparray

Tags: numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

I am confused about indexing NP arrays.
Assume we have to 2D nparrays.
`a.shape` is `(21,3)`
and `b.shape` is `(225,300)`
b contains values that do not exceed a index range.
Now my question is what doe this do exactly?

```
a[b[:], :]
```

Comment: Do you mean all `b` values are in the [0,21) range?  Using the bare [:] doesn't  do anything.

Comment: What's the problem with testing?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array of values

```py
import numpy as np

num_values = 10

values = np.arange(100, 100 + num_values)

print(values)
# [100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109]
```

You can draw from them into the shape you want using [numpy integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) -- the resulting shape takes into account the shape of the `indices` array:

```py
indices = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 3], [2, 7, 0, 9]])
arr = values[indices]

print(arr)
# [[100 101 100 103]
#  [102 107 100 109]]
```

Your case is just a generalization of that

```py
values = np.random.rand(num_values, 3)
indices = np.random.randint(0, num_values, size=(5, 7))

arr = values[indices]

print(arr.shape)
# (5, 7, 3)
```